# How to remove google font from default rwd theme?

Tags: theme, css, rwd-theme

I would like to remove following line of code from default magento theme, but I can't find out how:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600" />
```

Is it in some obscure xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove without having to edit RWDs page.xml file.

Add the following to your themes local.xml file under the  handle

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><name>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</name></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the following file

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml

and remove/comment the line

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
```